# Creating Node.js Code to execute command on remote device using SSH connection

Tags: node.js, ssh

I`m using Node.js code and trying to connect to PaloAlto Firewall device using Node-SSH exec function, through the following code, in order to execute a command on the device and using the ssh connection and get its result into stream and then read it.

```
const ssh = new NodeSSH();
const {host} = config;
let connection;
connection = await ssh.connect(config);
try {    
     ssh.exec(command.script, { stream: 'both' }).then(function(output) {
                            this.logger.debug(`2DevTeam stdout: ${output.stdout}`);
                            this.logger.debug(`2DevTeam stderr: ${output.stderr}`);
                          })
} catch (ex) {
                this.logger.error(`[CONNECT ${executionId}]: Execution failure: 
                ${ex.message}"`)                    
}
```

However, it seems that the function ssh.exec is not executing and I can`t see the log nor the error of the catch;

**Please Help!**